# Which line of source code set the "context.Authentication.User" and the "IsAuthenticated" property

Tags: asp.net, owin

I read the source code of asp.net katana project. Could you please tell me which line of source code set the "context.Authentication.User" and the "IsAuthenticated" property?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried opening the code in Visual Studio and doing a Find References?

Answer (score 0):

I find code below:

```
public void AddUserIdentity(IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var newClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        IPrincipal existingPrincipal = _context.Request.User;
        if (existingPrincipal != null)
        {
            var existingClaimsPrincipal = existingPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (existingClaimsPrincipal == null)
            {
                IIdentity existingIdentity = existingPrincipal.Identity;
                if (existingIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    newClaimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(existingIdentity as ClaimsIdentity ?? new ClaimsIdentity(existingIdentity));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var existingClaimsIdentity in existingClaimsPrincipal.Identities)
                {
                    if (existingClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        newClaimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(existingClaimsIdentity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        _context.Request.User = newClaimsPrincipal;
    }
```